# IFormFile is not bound if nested in view model

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, model-binding

I am having problem with binding nested IFormFile in .net core mvc project.
If I put my `IFormFile` in nested view model it will not be bound to it on post.
For example this does not work:

```
public class SomeVM
{
  public GalleryVM Gallery { get; set; }
}
public class GalleryVM
{
  public IFormFile UploadingImage { get; set; }
  //gallery properties...
}
```

View:

```
@model SomeVM

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="Gallery.UploadingImage" />
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
    </form>
```

Some code was omitted for brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to that so I want to share it with you. I found that it is known issue and it should be solved in .net core 2.0 [issue on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4485)

Current hack is to send some extra data when uploading file.

```
public class SomeVM
{
  public GalleryVM Gallery { get; set; }
}
public class GalleryVM
{
  public IFormFile UploadingImage { get; set; }
  public bool FormFileHack { get; set; }
  //gallery properties...
}

//the view .cshtml

<input type="file" name="Gallery.UploadingImage" />
<input type="hidden" name="Gallery.FormFileHack" />
```

Comment: Hello, I have the exact bug in .NET Core 3.1 with a small variation. Nesting IFormFile 'alone' results in a null in a whole parent object. Nesting it with some surrounding 'fake/hack' property results in a null in the IFormFile. The best part is that the proper file is always present in the Request.Form.Files[0], so the mapping between front and backend is correct.. Does anyone have some clue how to overcome this problem?

Comment: @newbie Did you solved that?